# How can I prevent my ajax action to be executed multiple times?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

index.php:

```
 <button class="create" data-id="12">create</button>
```

script.js:

```
$(".create").on('click', function () {

    var id = $(this).data('id');


    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
        }
    })
    $(this).unbind();
    return false;
});
```

update.php:

```
   $pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (id) values(:id) ');
            $pdo->execute(array(
                ':id' => $_POST['id'],
    ));
```

My problem the data is created multiple times in my database, even if I click only one time on the "create" button.

I try to prevent this by adding "$(this).unbind()" oder "return false". But this is not solving my problem

Comment: Assuming you mean that you only ever want the AJAX request to be made once, use `one()` instead of `on()`

Comment: try $(".create").one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Tested it, but not solving the problem

Comment: are you sure the issue is from ajax side? if then try event.preventDefault()

Comment: if I put `alert("fire");` directly after `$(".create").on('click', function () {` the alert box is popping up multiple times

Comment: I tested "event.preventDefault()" directly after "return false". Still firing multiple times

Comment: try `async: false,` - Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.

Comment: @Bhaskar how can that solve the issue?

Comment: @Bhaskar Then actually many things on my page do not work anymore

Comment: Hi, could you show us the whole scripts?

Comment: @Csimpi Unfortunately impossible, it is way to long to post it here

Comment: @Jarla by "multiple times" - how many times are we talking? also, are you using some type of header / meta to redirect to the same page? could be something in a form if you're using one and the button type; hard to say really. Look at your network tab also.

Comment: Jarla, if you need free help, you need to work with us :) I'm pretty sure the problem is in another part of the code

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, you are right. The problem must be somewhere else. I need to research into my code, if there is another issue. Thank you very much. I will post it, if I found the solution!

Comment: @Jarla welcome. Well, sometimes an input can cause this instead of a button along with a possible redirection to the same page; sounds like it to me.

Comment: @Csimpi Yes, I am sorry. I also guess now the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you, I will check this out

Comment: Check chrome debugging section and Network tab. You will see the problem with the JS or with the PHP. If in Network tab you can see the post request multiple times, something fire click event on item with .create  class.

Comment: @Jarla are you using a CMS ?

Comment: @Csimpi Thank you!

Comment: @DanPhilip No, only my code

Comment: I could created a simple example that makes more clear what causes my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493211/how-can-i-prevent-my-ajax-function-to-fire-multiple-time-on-click