# How can I prevent my Ajax function to fire multiple times on click?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.php

```
   <button class="cat" data-table="cat" >Cat</button>
   <div class="animals"></div>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).on("click", ".cat", function (event) {
    alert("cat");
    var table = $(this).data('table');
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: {

            table: table,
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".animals").html(data);
        }
    })
});

    $(document).on("click", ".dog", function (event) {
        alert("dog");
    var table = $(this).data('table');
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: {

            table: table,
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".animals").html(data);
        }
    })
});

   $(document).on("click", ".bird", function (event) {
       alert("bird");
    var table = $(this).data('table');
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: {

            table: table,
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".animals").html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

update.php

```
if ($table == "cat") {
    echo "<button class='dog' data-table='dog'>Dog</button>";   
}
if ($table == "dog") {
    echo "<button class='dog' data-table='dog'>Dog</button><button class='bird' data-table='bird'>bird</button>";   
}

if ($table == "bird") {
   echo "nothing";  
}
```

By click on an animal button (for example "bird") I expect the alert box fire only once. But everytime I click on an animal the alert box is firing more and more times.

Comment: You can try this. 
$(document).off('click').on("click", ".cat".....

Comment: I'm confused, why would you *expect* to see only one alert when you have coded 3, completely separate events handlers, each with its own alert?

Comment: @DavinderKumar Tested it. The button is not working anymore now

Comment: @freedomn-m No what I mean is: I click "bird" then it alerts only one "bird. But it alerts Bird Bird Bird

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Are you running your .js multiple times?

Comment: Do the ajax appended data has similar class names in it??

Comment: @DavinderKumar as it's using event delegation, that would turn off *all* delegated clicks on the page... unlikely something you'd actually want.

Comment: @abhiklpm Only what you see in my question.

Comment: @freedomn-m No only once

Comment: Just before this code `$(document).on("click", ".cat", ` add: `alert("init")` and see how many times it appears.

Comment: @freedomn-m `alert("init")` appears only once

Comment: Simplest way is you have to disable button on once clicked button and then enable it after ajax success

Comment: @AmanKumar No that is not working for me because I want to add also some mySQL inserts. And they unfortunately are inserted also multiple times

Comment: In all browsers??

Comment: @abhiklpm Tested in Safari and Firefox

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/868c0ya9/ this fiddle works fine, whats the issue, its not showing multiple alerts.. modify the fiddle if something wrong.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?  The code you've provided does not show any issue so any "solution" is pretty much a guess.  Have a read of this (if you haven't already) [mcve]

Comment: @freedomn-m Do you mean make a fiddle?

Comment: @abhiklpm Yes it is a different code. Not made with ajax and php

Comment: @freedomn-m I actually do not know how to make a php ajax fiddle

Comment: @Jarla comment the ajax part in your code and see how many times it triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .. 'Unbind'

```
 $('#updateUser').unbind('click').click(function () { 

  //do here ..
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Jarla :) #lovetohelpother.

Comment: Is it possible to use the "unbind" with "document on click" like  `$(document).on("click", ".dog", function (event) {`

Comment: try this   $(document).unbind('click').on('click', '#submitUser' , function () { // do herer})

Comment: Thank you, tested it, but my script is not working anymore. There must be some issue, I let you know if i figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Change your click event. use "one" instead of "on".Refer [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/) It will execute your click event only once. refer below example

```js
 $(document).one("click","#btn1",function(){
        alert("button btn1 clicked");
    });
    
    $(document).on("click","#btn2",function(){
        alert("button btn2 clicked");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js">
</script>

<button id="btn1">Click me(Executes once)</button>

<button id="btn2">Click me(Executes multiple times)</button>
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not working, because I need to be able to click another time one the button. I just want to prevent that on one click it will fire multiple times

Comment: You want to call ajax function multiple times??

Comment: Only one time when I click it. If I click on "bird" then there are no buttons "dog" and "bird" anymore. So of course I want to be able to click again on "cat" to get the buttons again

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
$('#do-something').click(function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( me.data('requestRunning') ) {
        return;
    }

    me.data('requestRunning', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<url>",
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            //stuffs
        },
        complete: function() {
            me.data('requestRunning', false);
        }
    });      
});
```

Comment: I tested it with my "cat" button, but then the "cat" button is not working anymore. Can you give an example for my cat button?

Comment: add data-requestRunning in your button

Comment: you mean like this? <button class="cat" data-table="cat" data-requestRunning="true" >Cat</button>

Comment: Right, depends upon "data-requestRunning" value you can change JS logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try with .off() before .on(), like this:

```
$(document).off().on("click", ".dog", function (event) {
        alert("dog");
    var table = $(this).data('table');
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: {

            table: table,
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".animals").html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct syntax for `.off()` ?

Comment: as it's using event delegation, this would turn off *all* delegated clicks on the page... unlikely something you'd actually want.

Comment: Try with $('body').on('click', '.dog', function({
// Do whatever
}))

Comment: Sorry @Jarla, the correct syntaxis is $('body').on('click', '.dog', function(){ alert('new dog') })

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.on` you can use `.one` method of jquery.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working, because I need to be able to click another time one the button. I just want to prevent that on one click it will fire multiple times

Comment: ok, You can also add condition before ajax fire by taking some default variable